# Self-powers residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, perfect-powers

> Let $a$, $x$ and $n$ three positive integers such that $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $x^x=a \mod n^n$.
> Prove that we can find a positive integer $y$ such that $y^y=a\mod n^{n^n}$.

This is what I managed to prove :

Let $x$, $a$ and $r$ positive integers such that $\gcd(a,r)=1$ and $x^x=a\mod r$, then we can find a positive integer $y$ such that $y^y=a\mod r\frac{r}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}$, where $\varphi$ denote the Euler's totient function.

Proof : Let $K$ be the integer such that $a=x^x+Kr$. By Bézout, there is a positive integer $k$ such that $k\,x^x\frac{\varphi(r)}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}=K\mod \frac{r}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}$. Then $y=x+k\,\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r))$ works.

**Edit1 :** Here are some details.
By binomial theorem, we have  $(x+a)^{x+a}\equiv(1+a)x^{x+a}\;[a^2]$,
so $y^y\equiv (1+k\,\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r)))x^{x+k\,\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r))}\;[\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r))^2]$.
Remember that $\gcd(m,n)\times\text{lcm}(m,n)=mn$.
$\gcd(r,\varphi(r))=1$, so $x^{\varphi(r)}\equiv1 \;[r]$, and by binomial theorem, $\left(x^{\varphi(r)}\right)^{\frac{r}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}}\equiv1 \;\left[\frac{r^2}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}\right]$,
so $x^{\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r))}\equiv1 \;\left[\frac{r^2}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}\right]$.
Thus $y^y\equiv(1+k\,\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r)))x^x\;\left[\frac{r^2}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}\right]$.
But $kx^x\,\text{lcm}(r,\varphi(r))\equiv Kr\;\left[\frac{r^2}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}\right]$, so $y^y\equiv a\;\left[\frac{r^2}{\gcd(r,\varphi(r))}\right]$.

**Edit2 :** Thanks to the link given by BillyJoe, I realized that the previous proof works with $\widetilde{\varphi}(r)$ instead of $\varphi(r)$, where $\widetilde{\varphi}(r)=\text{lcm}\left\{(p-1)p^{\nu_p(r)-1}\,,\,p\text{ prime with }p\,|\,r \right\}$, because if $r=n^n$, forall prime $p$ such that $p\,|\,r$, we have $p \,|\,\frac{r}{\gcd(r,\widetilde{\varphi}(r))}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You've been here over a decade. You should know better by now.

Comment: I added some context. This is an old exercise that I found in my papers. Sorry, I don't have any additional information.

Comment: I have also included the proof of my result.

Comment: Are you sure this result is true?

Comment: I do not remember the source of this exercise... If you found a counterexample, I would be interested...

Comment: Surely the ridiculous nested power $n^{n^n}$ is not actually important, and you can actually prove it for something like every power of $n$.

Comment: Do you think that something like $(x^x=a\mod n) \Rightarrow (\forall\alpha,\, \exists y, \; y^y=a\mod n^{\alpha})$ is true ?

Comment: This property is true if for all prime factors $p$ and $q$ of $n$, $p$ does not divide $q-1$ (see my result above). Example : if $n$ is a prime power.

Comment: I don't see how putting $y= x+ \mathrm{lcm}(r,\varphi(r))$ works. Could you give a bit more details?

Comment: I added some details

Comment: Using [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5Ex%3Da%20%5Cmod%20n%5En%24&p=1) I have found the [following solutions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1301963p6940755).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will study this solution.

Comment: This doesn't make sense you are given that $x^x$ is congurent to a mod n, so let $x=y$, or do you want to show there are two solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.